# How to use output clause in c# when inserting multiple records to get all id's?

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my c# code, I have this function

```
public static List<T> SELECT<T>(string command, Func<SqlDataReader, T> f, Dictionary<string, object> h)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(mySetting.ConnectionString);
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(command, myConnection);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in h)
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    List<T> lst = new List<T>();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        lst.Add(f(myReader));
    }
    myConnection.Close();
    return lst;
}
```

But how can I use the output clause in this to get an array of integers representing the list of id's? Does this support temp tables?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the generic method signature what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you inserting data?

Comment: OUTPUT clause in what? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Does it work for one new entry?  Does all your new entries goes well to the database?  It should work like any SELECT query.  Do you have any exception or error?

Comment: Sean, Omega talk about this OUTPUT clause  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: what string are you passing as the command?

Comment: @DanielBlais I know about OUTPUT in sql server but there is absolutely no context for sql here because there is ZERO t-sql in this question.

Comment: This is a generic funciton, and I assume the sql command is, in `command` variable, which no example has been provided.